# Split string with <br> and limit to certain number of characters in Javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to split a string with new line and if you find a whitespace when the limited of characters is reached bypass that word and then create the new line(br)?
is there any JQuery plugin or some Javascript code to achieve this?

example:

limit to 10 characters:

```
phrase:
tres tristes tigres tragaban trigo en un trigal.

instead of this:
tres trist
es tigres 
tragaban t
rigo en un
 trigal.

achieve this:
tres tristes 
tigres tragaban
trigo en un
trigal.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the: [ http://phpjs.org/functions/wordwrap/ ], you'll find the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty:

```
var phrase = 'tres tristes tigres tragaban trigo en un trigal.';
var limit = 10;

var parts = phrase.split(' ');

var sentence = '';

for(i = 0; i <= parts.length -1; i++) {
    var word = i == parts.length-1 ? parts[i] : parts[i] + ' ';
    sentence += word;

    if(sentence.length > limit && i != parts.length-1) {
        document.write(sentence.trim() + '<br>');
        sentence = '';
    } else if (i == parts.length-1) {
        document.write(sentence);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about looping through the string and checking if you're over 10 characters and on a white space?
http://jsfiddle.net/ajetd/

```
function breakString(myString, breakLen) {
    var count = 0,
        retString = "";

    for (i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
        retString += myString[i];
        if (count >= breakLen && myString[i].replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0) {
            retString += '<br/>';
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
    }

    return retString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var str = "bla blah blach nhhnhnhfdfdfdfdf"
 splity(str)

 function splity(strr) {

 ten = 9;
   for(i=0; i < str.length; i++){
     document.write(str[i])

       if ((ten <= i) && (str[i] == " ")) {
         ten = ten*2
           document.write("<break>");       
  }}}
```

simple but effective :)